# Alfresco Community Edition (5.1) integration with Facebook, Twitter,

Tags: facebook, twitter, alfresco

I tried to find some documentation on how to connect Alfresco CE to Facebook and/or Twitter.

The docs only describe it only in the 4.1.x enterprise edition (http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/adminconsole-channelsman-intro.html) but there no similar section in the 5.1 CE docs.

The good Jeff Pots Tutorial on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpsSJML1-iE is somewhat outdated, and does only cover sharing documents.

I'd like to share some content (blog) to Facebook and Twitter (and possibly others) rather tan files from within the CE.

Is this (not?) possible in CE and can someone guide me into the right direction.

Comment: Do you just want an easy way to create public URLs for specific documents and post those to twitter/facebook? Or something else?

Comment: The idea is to automate distribution of "content" (news, etc.) to various social media at once. 
Simple example: invitation to an even posted on FB, Twitter, Linkedin.
It's not the main intent to share documents.
Maybe this is the wrong approach, but who knows.

Comment: I think you're going to need to write some code. Shouldn't be too bad though, Alfresco has support for storing OAuth2 credentials, the spring social libraries ought to help with the logic stuff etc

Comment: But what's about [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/library-item-publish.html)?

Comment: I've got a feeling it was only ever used in demos, and was removed...

Comment: It's so frustrating as the docu is sooo bad.
Nothing to recommend to a customer.

Comment: What docs are so bad? All the built-in features should be well explained on docs.alfresco.com!

Answer (score 1):

It's not included anymore
[Alfresco statement](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/integration-other-systems/facebook-twitter-ce)